# Obj-C and multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Whats the best way to deal with multi-dimensional arrays in Obj-C? I've read everything form creating NSArray's of NSArrays, use C style arrays and some even suggested tossing in STL and go with c++ style arrays....

I'm in the need of a 3 dimensional array of objects. Is the best thing a NSArray of NSArrays of NSArrays? That seems convoluted. Is there any object out there that can deal with n-dimensional arrays in a nice clean clear api?

A clean and clear api example:

```
obj = [MDArray getLayer: 1 atX: 10 atY: 10];
[MDArray setLayer: 1 atX: 10 atY: 10 withValue: object];
```

If it makes a difference, my end goal is map data for a game. I'm used to the C style of things, but am trying hard to use obj-c (learning as I go).

Comment: You can use `NSArray` with `NSArray` with `NSArray`... I mean it's relatively straightforward to traverse such a structure. It's a bit difficult to advise as you haven't stated a clear goal as to what you want to do.

Comment: What's the data you're working with? An NSDictionary might be better suited. You could also make a subclass called `MDArray` and write code that'll give you the objects you want.

Comment: Don't name methods `get*` anything unless you are following standard Cocoa/UIKit patterns [returning multiple values by reference].

Comment: @bbum - is there a url I can look at to learn the Cocoa/UIKit way of doing things? I've always used get* when I return something so its just habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is natural to suggest nesting, but a waste of time unless you need something that can do sparse arrays.

A better solution is to create an NSMutableArray and fill it with NSNulls or an NSPointerArray, which allows for nulls via the `setCount:` method.

Then, if you need, say, to be able to handle objects at coordinates (0..3,0..3,0..3), that is 4*4*4 (or 64) slots.

From there, turning an (x,y,z) coord into a slot in the array is just a matter of multiplication;   (1,2,3) is the object at index (1 + (2 * width) + (3 * width * height)).

That simple bit of math avoids a bunch of extra allocations (and the potential that your extra allocations fragment memory).  While I'm all for not prematurely optimizing, the math is straightforward whereas the allocation dance is not -- this'll be easier to implement in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, as Aurum said in the comments, writing your own multi dimensional array wrapper.

It would be relatively simple - the wrapper would own the Array of Arrays of Arrays, but expose methods like you describe which hide away the relatively ugly code of traversing the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is no multi-dimensional array in the standard library. I would wrap the thing in my own class, it’s quite simple to do. The implementation would be nested `NSArray`s or plain C arrays, if the former solution *proves* to be slow.