# 2 Dimensional array within another 2dimensional array in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am looking for an method to create and mulidimensional array in objective C.

my requirement is an array similar to

```
 float array = new float [3*2];
 float array = new float [[3*2][3*2]];
```

these two being  in a java format

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me in how i can initialize such arrays in objective-c . 
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362740/creating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848768/obj-c-and-multi-dimensional-arrays)

[2D arrays using NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724772/2d-arrays-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a superset of C, and any C code is valid Objective-C as well - so, this is a link to creating multidimensional arrays in C: [Wikipedia's Article: C syntax - Multidimensional arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Multidimensional_arrays)

However, if you're looking for the Objective-C way to do it, that would be to use `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray`.