# C-style Multidimensional Array in ARC Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement an n x n multidimensional array of ints in Objective-C, and because using NSMutableArray seems to be too much of an overhead I decided to implement it using only C's malloc and free. My question is, is the code below correct (no memory leaks) under ARC Objective-C?

```
@interface TwoDimensionalArray
{
    int **array;
    int size;
}
@end

@implementation TwoDimensionalArray
- (id)initWithSize: (int)s
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        size = s;
        array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return self
}
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithSize:1];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
        array[i] = nil;
    }
    free(array);
    array = nil;
}
@end
```

If this is not correct, or if you think there is a definitely better way to do it in Objective-C without doing mallocs, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Why is `NSMutableArray` too much of an overhead? Did you use Instruments to identify performance problems?

Comment: You don't need to zero your array contents if you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: On a pedantic side note: you should be using NULL instead of nil for your array pointer. nil is meant to be used for Obj-C object pointers.

Comment: Also, if I am not mistaken, OP has created an array of `int`s, which can't be held in an `NSArray` anyway.

Comment: @Monolo You can wrap it into an `NSNumber` object ;)

Comment: @HAS Actually, I agree with you for the wrapping part (the "new" numeric literals make it nearly painless). The unwrapping from NSNumber to primitive types is still slightly less elegant, so I'll say your comment is half right as I see it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ARC implements automatic memory management for *Objective-C objects* and *blocks*, but does not
automate *malloc/free*.
(References: [Clang/ARC documentation: General](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general), 
[ARC Release Notes: FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17).)

So your question is unrelated to ARC: Everything you `malloc()` must be
`free()`'d (and `dealloc` is good place to do so). From the first look your code looks OK.

(Small remarks: Zeroing the array pointers in `dealloc` is not necessary, but
`NULL` would be the appropriate pointer value to assign, `nil` is meant for Objective-C objects.)

I do not know how much overhead using Objective-C collections such as `NSMutableArray`
would cause, that should be tested (as already said in the comments) by profiling.

Comment: I find it easier to use a single allocation and straightforward math than nested allocations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848768/obj-c-and-multi-dimensional-arrays